# attach get/set function to objects property in js

Tags: javascript, oop, binding

I essentially have an object:

```
var foo = function() {
  this.setting = false;
  this.refresh = function() { ... };
}

let a = new foo();
a.setting = true; // a.refresh() is triggered
```

I need to trigger refresh anytime `.setting` is written to. I feel like it has something to do with `bind`, but I couldn't quite get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a getter and a setter for your object. One way is to use getter/setter functions directly:

```
var foo = function()
{
   this.setting = false;
   this.getSetting = function() { return this.setting; }
   this.setSetting = function(val) { this.setting = val; this.refresh(); }
   this.refresh = function()
   {...}
}
```

If you want to use foo.setting transparently as an attribute, there are language constructs for that, but unfortunately they are not interoperable across browsers. In somewhat of a throwback to 3 years ago, there's one method supported by Mozilla, Safari, Chrome and Opera and another method for Internet Explorer. This is the standard method:

http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/

IE9 has something else, and I'm not sure if it even works for non-DOM objects.

Comment: yea real get/set functions were what i was going for. none of those work on my platform unfortunately. thanks for the help

Comment: IE9 works the same as Chrome and FF, IE8 supports it *only* on DOM objects, IE7 and earlier have no support for getters and setters.

Answer (score 13):

You could use JavaScript getters and setters. See [the MDC documentation on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) and [John Resig's blog post on the subject](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/). Note that not all browsers support this.

```
var Foo = function()//constructor
{
   this._settings = false;//hidden variable by convention
   this.__defineGetter__("settings", function(){
     return _settings;//now foo.settings will give you the value in the hidden var
   });

   this.__defineSetter__("settings", function(s){
      _settings = s;//set the hidden var with foo.settings = x
      this.refresh();//trigger refresh when that happens
   });

   this.refresh = function(){
      alert("Refreshed!");//for testing
   }
}

var a = new Foo();//create new object
a.settings = true;//change the property
//a.refresh() is triggered
```

**[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/HBBzB/)**

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a setting setter? Something like this?

```
// renamed settings property with underscore
this._settings = false;

this.settings = function(s) {
     if(s !== undefined) {
        this._settings = s;
        this.refresh();
     }

     return this._settings;
};

...


var f = new foo();
f.setSettings(mySettings);
```

I tend to combine my getter and setter into one method in JavaScript since it's so easy to do. The downside to this is `_settings` is still public on your object and anyone can directly write to it. The only way to hide it is to use a closure, which requires a totally different approach to creating your objects.

Comment: yea this is what i have now, i was hoping i could only make the _settings public and hide the get/set functions

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't limited with old browsers you may try to use the approach described [here](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/)

Answer (score 3):

I don't why you are trying to use the "new" operator, you will be better using the object literal. Now, if you are looking similar to, let's say, C# properties, you could do something like this:

```
var myObject = function(){
    //Private Members
    var myProperty = '';

        //Privileged Setter
        this.setMyProperty = function(value){
            myProperty = value;
        };

        //Privileged Getter
        this.getMyProperty = function(){
            return myProperty;
        }

}

var MyNewObject = new myObject();
MyNewObject.setMyProperty("Hello, World!");
MyNewObject.getMyProperty();
```

For more info, I recommend this: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: -1 You use the `new` operator to correctly setup prototypes...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old question that has already been answered, but I'd like to provide a solution that takes advantage of JavaScript's latest syntax.*

---

Define a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this._setting = false;
  }

  get setting() {
    return this._setting;
  }

  set setting(value) {
    this._setting = value;
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh() {
    console.log("refresh!");
  }
}

let foo = new Foo();
foo.setting = true; // foo.refresh() is called
```